# How to install Postgresql in Vagrant box

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm trying to install postgresql in a vagrant box but am having no luck. I tried provisioning with Chef AND Puppet then finally just ssh'd into the box and tried apt-get install... 
the result is the same.

Via chef:

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[postgresql-client] (postgresql::client line 37) had an error: apt-get -q -y install postgresql-client=8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04 returned 100, expected 0
```

via apt-get

```
apt-get install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpq5 postgresql-8.4 postgresql-client-8.4 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common ssl-cert
Suggested packages:
  oidentd ident-server postgresql-doc-8.4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpq5 postgresql postgresql-8.4 postgresql-client-8.4 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
  ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,899kB/4,952kB of archives.
After this operation, 20.6MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libpq5 8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main postgresql-client-8.4 8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main ssl-cert 1.0.23ubuntu2 [10.9kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main postgresql-common 106ubuntu1 [88.2kB]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main postgresql-8.4 8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main postgresql 8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Fetched 99.2kB in 1s (91.7kB/s)
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-8.4/libpq5_8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-8.4/postgresql-client-8.4_8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-8.4/postgresql-8.4_8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-8.4/postgresql_8.4.8-0ubuntu0.10.04_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Anybody experience this or am i just a dummy? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess: Your cached source indexes are out of date; run

```
apt-get clean; apt-get update
```

and then try again. Another possibility is a proxy server (possibly transparent) that's breaking the request, or even a bad mirror. If you confirm a proxy isn't the problem, try using a different mirror in your /etc/apt/sources.list .

This isn't really a PostgreSQL question; suggest untagging it.

Comment: That was it. :) Untagged as Postgresql

Comment: I disagree with this answer - or rather, it is incomplete. We should be able to run apt-get update as part of the Chef provisioning before running the postgres recipe.

Comment: See answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246786/how-can-i-get-chef-to-run-apt-get-update-before-running-other-recipes/9250730#9250730